# How to set marks for scale questions in quiz module?

Tags: quiz

I am using [quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module to set up a self-evaluation quiz, which consists of five scale questions, the answer of each question is preset (from "always" to "never"). After setting up the quiz I took a test, and got the result "...got 30 of 30 possible points.Total score: 100 %". Choose any answer I got the same result! I have already set in quiz that if the total score from 0-6 suggest result A, 7-12 suggest result B...However, I could not really get the correct result. I suspect it must be I have not defined the mark of each answer at different scale, but I could not find anywhere to define the marks. Can anybody help please?